# Input without typing definition?

Tags: python

I am writing a code in python which imports data from an excel doc to check whether a patron's recreational 5-digit pass is still valid or not. Here is the code so far:

```
import datetime
class Patron:
    def __init__(self, num, expiry, lastname, firstname, length):
        self.num = num
        self.expiry = expiry
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.length = length

d = [i.strip() for i in open("names.csv")][1:]
patrons = [Patron(*x.split(",")) for x in d]

now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = str(now.year)+"-"+str(now.month)+"-"+str(now.day)

def search(x):
    n=0
    for i in patrons:
        n+=1
        if i.num == str(x):
            if today < i.expiry:
                print("Valid through "+ i.expiry)
            else:
                print("EXPIRED " + i.expiry)
            break
        elif n == len(patrons):
            print("Number not found")
        else:
            continue
```

Right now, in order to use the search function, the user has to type in:

```
search(12345)
```

How do I write the code so the program simply asks the user:

```
Enter number here:_____
```

Comment: `search(input("Enter number here: "))` ?

Comment: Try `search(int(input("Enter number here: ")))`

Comment: @RafaelC if you are using Python 2, you shouldn't use `input` to begin with

Comment: @RafaelC using search(input("Enter number here: ")) works, but it only works on boot up. How do I get that input prompt to show every time immediately after a pass is checked?